# Get specific value from a formatted string in Python

Tags: python

I'm calling a CLI utility (using subprocess.popen) and I need to parse out a value from the output. The output looks something like this:

```
Data for user id: jsmith

User id . . . . . . . . . . . : jsmith
User key  . . . . . . . . . . : jsmith
Full name . . . . . . . . . . : Joe Smith
Email . . . . . . . . . . . . : joe.smith@delphix.com
Time zone . . . . . . . . . . : America/Los_Angeles
```

What's the best way to parse this so I can get the value for User Key, Full name, and Email? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't here to do your work for you. However, if you show that you've tried something and have run into difficulties, we'll be happy to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.findall` function.

```
>>> s = '''Data for user id: jsmith

User id . . . . . . . . . . . : jsmith
User key  . . . . . . . . . . : jsmith
Full name . . . . . . . . . . : Joe Smith
Email . . . . . . . . . . . . : joe.smith@delphix.com
Time zone . . . . . . . . . . : America/Los_Angeles'''
>>> re.findall(r'\b(User\s+key|Full\s+name|Email)\b.*:\s*(.*)', s)
[('User key', 'jsmith'), ('Full name', 'Joe Smith'), ('Email', 'joe.smith@delphix.com')]
```

You could convert the output of findall to dictionary using `dict` function.

```
>>> dict(re.findall(r'\b(User\s+key|Full\s+name|Email)\b.*:\s*(.*)', s))
{'Email': 'joe.smith@delphix.com', 'Full name': 'Joe Smith', 'User key': 'jsmith'}
```

Add `re.IGNORECASE` parameter if you want to do a case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the non-blank lines and grab the values like this:

```
x.split(":")[1][1:]
```

where x is the string on that line, assuming there are no colons in the values